# Why is login time not recorded correctly

Tags: support, consecutive-days, time

I stay logged on to stackoverflow on my browser. But the consecutive day count seems to not show up correctly. For example I visited the site late Sunday night (today is Monday) and saw the counter for Monday already incremented. I visit the site again less than 24 hours later. I see the consecutive day count set to 1 with Monday being skipped while it is still Monday in my Time Zone (EST). While it is OK for Stackoverflow to stick to one time zone but why do the two visits in the 24 hour interval not count Monday?
Why was Monday counted on Sunday night itself but on Monday it shows as not counted?

Comment: Because SE runs on UTC time. It doesn't care about your local time. You can see what the current server time is by hovering over your username in the top bar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visiting the site and *refreshing a page* isn't enough in any 24hr period. Being active and actually doing something is!

I learnt this **the hard way** a few months ago, after noting that my profile page didn't update the 'seen' row when I viewed the page (in isolation of doing anything else).

It's too late for me now, but *you could still escape*, have a life outside of SO and avoid the addiction that WILL follow as a result of your question!